# Does R1 game update in PSN Asia account

Tags: ps3, psn

I bought a game in R1 region. Now my PSN account is logged in and I am registered in Hongkong and located in Philippines. Will the game still automatically see the update for my R1 game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Game updates are region-independent, so they update even if your PSN account is from a different game region than the game.

In fact, you can download game updates even if you're not connected to the PSN.